# Spring Cloud Dataflow - Docker compose in windows local - Failed to resolve MavenResource

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

Running spring cloud dataflow docker compose in my windows local.

Created http|log stream using below command
stream create --definition "http --server.port=8080 | log" --name myhttpstream

When i deploy this stream getting below exception.

[Failed to resolve MavenResource: org.springframework.cloud.stream.app:http-source-rabbit:jar:3.2.1. Configured remote repository: : [springRepo]]

```
Could not install AppDeployRequest [[AppDeploymentRequest@69027f98 commandlineArguments = list[[empty]], deploymentProperties = map['spring.cloud.deployer.appName' -> 'http', 'spring.cloud.deployer.group' -> 'myhttpstream'], definition = [AppDefinition@47999dbb name = 'http-v1', properties = map['management.endpoints.web.exposure.include' -> 'health,info,bindings', 'management.metrics.tags.application.type' -> '${spring.cloud.dataflow.stream.app.type:unknown}', 'spring.cloud.dataflow.stream.app.label' -> 'http', 'management.metrics.tags.stream.name' -> '${spring.cloud.dataflow.stream.name:unknown}', 'management.metrics.tags.application' -> '${spring.cloud.dataflow.stream.name:unknown}-${spring.cloud.dataflow.stream.app.label:unknown}-${spring.cloud.dataflow.stream.app.type:unknown}', 'spring.rabbitmq.host' -> 'rabbitmq', 'spring.cloud.dataflow.stream.name' -> 'myhttpstream', 'management.metrics.tags.instance.index' -> '${vcap.application.instance_index:${spring.cloud.stream.instanceIndex:0}}', 'wavefront.application.service' -> '${spring.cloud.dataflow.stream.app.label:unknown}-${spring.cloud.dataflow.stream.app.type:unknown}-${vcap.application.instance_index:${spring.cloud.stream.instanceIndex:0}}', 'spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.producer.requiredGroups' -> 'myhttpstream', 'management.metrics.tags.application.guid' -> '${spring.cloud.application.guid:unknown}', 'server.port' -> '8080', 'spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.destination' -> 'myhttpstream.http', 'management.metrics.tags.application.name' -> '${vcap.application.application_name:${spring.cloud.dataflow.stream.app.label:unknown}}', 'spring.cloud.dataflow.stream.app.type' -> 'source', 'wavefront.application.name' -> '${spring.cloud.dataflow.stream.name:unknown}']], resource = org.springframework.cloud.stream.app:http-source-rabbit:jar:3.2.1]] to platform [default]. Error Message = [Failed to resolve MavenResource: org.springframework.cloud.stream.app:http-source-rabbit:jar:3.2.1. Configured remote repository: : [springRepo]]
```

should be able to deploy http|log stream in my local windows machine using docker-compose

Answer (score 1):

The permissions have changed for `repo.spring.io` ([details](https://spring.io/blog/2022/12/14/notice-of-permissions-changes-to-repo-spring-io-january-2023)).

- **Before** the permission change `repo.spring.io/lib-snapshot` resolved basically everything.
- **After** the change, `repo.spring.io/snapshot` is instead used - which only resolves Spring SNAPSHOT artifacts (not 3rd party). Because of this, other remote repos must be configured.

SCDF `2.10.3` has been updated to address this. Which version of SCDF are you using?

If you are still seeing the issue you can try manually configuring the required remote repos following these steps in the [SCDF ref guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/2.10.3/reference/htmlsingle/#configuration-maven).

The list of required remote repos are:

```
maven:
  remoteRepositories:
    mavenCentral:
      url: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2
    springSnapshot:
      url: https://repo.spring.io/snapshot
    springMilestone:
      url: https://repo.spring.io/milestone
```